# How To get Child User Control Value on the Button Click of Parent User Control

Tags: asp.net

I have a Button on the Parent User control and a text box on the child user control.

Now I wants to get the text from the Text box on the click of Parent Button click.

I mean I want to get the Child user control values from the parent.

How can i do it in asp.net.

Comment: dalvir , you should use events for these , raise a event on the child control and listen the same on the parent

Answer (score 1):

dalvir , you should use events for these , raise a event on the child control and listen the same on the parent

here is the answer for you

[Sharing value from child to parent control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909269/sharing-value-from-child-to-parent-control)

Answer (score 0):

It is all there in your Form control collection... you can try

```
TextBox text = Form.FindControl("name") as TextBox;
```